# Copiar struct C

Tags: c

Como faço a copia de um ponteiro do tipo `struct` em C?

Por exemplo, pra copiar uma struct simples é apenas `struct1 = struct2`; 
mas, quando se trata de 2 ponteiros, quando faz isso, uma aponta pro mesmo local da outra, e então da na mesma, o conteúdo altera na original, queria saber um jeito de fazer uma cópia de um ponteiro para outro, porém apenas do conteúdo, não do endereço de memória.

---

Comment: *ponteiro1 = *ponteiro2;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumindo que cada um dos ponteiros aponta para um sítio válido

```
struct whatever {int a; int b; int c;};
struct whatever array[2];
struct whatever *p1, *p2;
p1 = array;       // p1 aponta para o primeiro elemento do array
p2 = array + 1;   // p2 aponta para o segundo elemento do array
array[0].a = array[0].b = array[0].c = 42;    // atribui valores a array[0] e *p1

*p2 = *p1;              // copia

printf("%d %d %d\n", array[1].a, array[1].b, array[1].c); // prints 42 42 42
```

Se for preciso alocar memória, o método é o mesmo

```
struct whatever *p3 = NULL;
p3 = malloc(sizeof *p3);
if (p3) {
    *p3 = *p1;             // copia
    /* use p3 */
    free(p3);
} else /* error */;
```

Comment: `*p3 = *p1 ; free(p3)`  não falta nada?

Comment: Estava a pensar o mesmo @JJoao

Comment: `*p3 = *p1; /* use p3 */; free(p3);` ... pronto! Não tou a ver o que falta.

Comment: (Quando estava `malloc; atritui; free` induzia em erro: o uso tem que ser antes do free claro) assim está mais claro. +1